# Test DOMParser using Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, domparser

I have a method which uses DOMParser to parse a XML, like this:

```
this.parseXmlString = function(xmlDocStr) {
    var xmlDoc;
    var parser= new window.DOMParser();

    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString( xmlDocStr, "text/xml" );
    // here I do some stuff with xmlDoc

    return xmlDoc;
};
```

The problem is: when I try to make a unit test with Jest of this function `window.DOMParser` is undefined. The test is as simple as:

```
expect(x2js.parseXmlString(xmlDocStr)).toMatchObject(expectedObject);
```

Is there any way I can use DOMParser from a Jest unit test?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to `window` reference. Just use `new DOMParser()...`. Make sure you have `"testEnvironment": "jsdom"` in your Jest configuration (it should be the [default](http://testEnvironment) though).

I've created an example here. https://repl.it/@ChrisPaton/FlusteredNearDecimal

You will also most likely need the latest version of Jest, as `jsdom` only [added support](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1368) for `DOMParser` and `XMLSerializer` in late October.

**Update**

JSDom is [not supported](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7537) above v11 by Jest. You'll need to configure a custom environment for this. Here is a link to their [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting#compatibility-issues) and here is a link to a [custom jsdom environment](https://github.com/theneva/jest-environment-jsdom-thirteen) that is easy to use. I hope this helps.

Comment: I finally did a workaround to have this done, but your answer is much better.